# How can I use ruby-debugger inside of a resque job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, ruby-debug

I'm looking for a command to start a worker process so that inside of the job's `perform` method I can call `debugger` and have control thrown to the command prompt.

Comment: Do you use any IDEs? How do you set breakpoints now?

Comment: If you call 'debugger' in your ruby code it's treated as a breakpoint.

Comment: What about running the task outside of Resque?

Comment: It's really annoying to do with the way the code is structured

Comment: @James I not sure debugger would be ever halt for a `fork` process I tried it number of time without any luck but I know for sure `pry` would work the way u need I tested it against passenger spawner and it gave the desired output that u r looking for

Comment: I will give pry a try!!!!!!!! Thanks. FWIW I have had the debugger halt for the forked process. I can't remember the command I used to start the worker process...

Comment: Pry solved it. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) instead of ruby-debugger. Works like a charm. Practically an Irish charm!

Comment: Can you tell me how you pry it? I have a resque error on production, I know where it's coming from, but I don't know how to pry into it. Do you use pry-rails? If so, does that mean you have to commit new code to production to use it?

Answer (score 2):

instead of calling `Resque.enqueue(Archive, self.id, branch)` (from the resque readme), I think you should be able to call `Archive.perform(self.id, branch)`.  Doing this, you should be able to use debugger inside the worker.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to your rails app
Resque.inline = true
this causes the resque jobs not be enqueued but to be executed immediately

Comment: Where to add this line.

Comment: config/initializers/resque.rb